# Laravel: How to transfer files via SFTP to Azure Blob Storage without downloading other libraries?

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service, sftp

I need to be able to transfer files, list files and delete files on a certain directory on my Azure Blob Storage and use existing Laravel Disk commands like `put()`, `allFiles()`, `delete()`.

Below is my code for uploading a file:

```
use Storage;

class SFTPFileUploader
{
    public function uploadFileToAzure($fileName,$content)
    {
        $sftpAzureDisk= Storage::disk('sftp');
        $sftpAzureDisk->put($fileName,$content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this without having to download other libraries,

First you need make sure you have the following setup in your Azure Portal

```
1. Azure Storage Account (e.g myprojectstorage)
2. Azure Storage Container (e.g myprojectcontainerfolder)
3. Azure Storage Account -> Settings -> SFTP
      3.1 Create a Local User (If none yet)
          3.1.1 Create User Name
          3.1.2 Generate Password
          3.1.3 Set Permissions
      3.2 Enable SFTP
```

After setting all of those, you can proceed to your `config/filesystems.php` and create new connection

```
'sftp' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => "<myprojectstorage>.blob.core.windows.net",
            'port' => 22,
            'username' => "<myprojectstorage>.<myprojectcontainer>.<username>",
            'password' => <password>,
            'privateKey' => storage_path('app/public/your.key'),//optional depends on Azure Setup
            'root' => '/',
        ],
```

then this should already work without having to download any other library,

```
use Storage;

class SFTPFileUploader
{
    public function uploadFileToAzure($fileName,$content)
    {
        $sftpAzureDisk= Storage::disk('sftp');
        $sftpAzureDisk->put($fileName,$content);
    }
}
```

P.S (I only have tested working using with Password, not tested yet for Key File)